# Is there a reliable reproduction rate for adenoviruses?

Tags: virology

I was trying to find a R0 for adenoviruses but the best I could find was a study done in a [bootcamp in China](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0232948) that infected 375 people.

This states that the R0 was found to be 5.1:

> The basic reproductive number was 5.1 (95% CI: 4.6 to 5.6)

Is there any other more reliable method that covers more data?

Comment: I expect it depends on the virus strain, social conditions etc. As such, this isn't a very good question.

Comment: @Fizz Well obviously, that is why the one example from the study isn't a very relevant answer - the R0 can vary, but all viruses generally have a mean R0 or range, that is what I am trying to find out.